# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable in Flask when using FastText model

Tags: python, json, flask, curl

I am new to flask. I want to use FastText to do the language detection. And wrapped it in flask.

language_predict.py

```
import fasttext

class Language:

    def __init__(self):

        model = "lid.176.bin"
        self.model = fasttext.load_model(model)

    def predict_lang(self, text):

        predictions = self.model.predict(text, k=1)
        return predictions
```

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, request
from language_predict import Language
app = Flask(__name__)

LANGUAGE = Language()

@app.route('/detect', methods=['POST'])
def add_message():
    content = request.json
    lang = LANGUAGE.predict_lang(content['text'])
    return {"lang":lang[0][0], "score": lang[1][0]}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host= '127.0.0.1', port= 5000)
```

When I run the app.py, and send a request in cmd:

```
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/detect_language -d "{\"text\":\"hello\"}" -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

it has the TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

How can I fix that?

Here is the stack trace

```
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\Python\language-identification-master\language-identification-master\app.py", line 16, in add_message
    lang = LANGUAGE.predict_lang(content['text'])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Dec/2020 18:07:58] "POST /detect_language HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Comment: Try printing `content` to see if your script is actually receiving the json data. I also don't know if curl is specific about having keyword arguments before the main argument, but you could try:
`curl -d "{\"text\":\"hello\"}" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/detect_language`

Comment: Please show the complete stack trace

Comment: @DaveW.Smith Hi, I updated.

Comment: Try simplifying the curl command. -X might not be doing what you expect, and -d implies POST. Try ```curl -d '{"text": "hello"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://127.0.0.1:5000/detect_language```

Answer (score 0):

its `request.json()` not `request.json` , `.json` is not an attribute, thats y `content` has the value NoneType

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).